# How do I combine the weights of two predictor in a regression model with GRNN?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, python, approximation

I am trying to build an algorithm that uses GRNN for regression, a model based on the formula:
[image]

My csv files are looks like:

```
Train.csv:                               Test.csv:
Number1  Number2  NumberT                Number1  Number2
2        4        3                      5        7
4        6        5
6        8        7
8        10       9
```

Predictors are `Number1` and `Number2`. My Target is `NumberT`. It is pretty easy to predict the output with only 1 predictor `Number1`. But when multiple features comes in, I can't figure it out.

To solve this problem, I have stored all the features and outputs automatically:

```
inputsTrain = [[2,4,6,8],[4,6,8,10]]
outputsTrain = [3,5,7,9]
inputsTest = [[5],[7]]
```

I've used `inputsTrain` and `outputsTrain` to find the weights by activation function. (I assumed `σ=1`).
To calculate the weights, I found all the distances between inputsTest and inputsTrain.

```
for test input 5: euc_distances = [[9, 1, 1, 9], [1, 1, 9, 25]]
for test input 7: euc_distances = [[25, 9, 1, 1], [9, 1, 1, 9]]
```

After inserting these distances into the activation function, I have stored all the weights in a list called `hiddenLayers`.

```
weights = [[[0, 0.6, 0.6, 0], [0.6, 0.6, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0.6, 0.6], [0, 0.6, 0.6, 0]]]
```

But now I don't know what to do with these weights. It was easy when I got 1 predictor, I could just multiply weights with corresponding `outputsTrain` elements and then do numerator/denominator. But when it comes to **multiple predictors**, I can't find what to do after this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright seems like I had to apply the same method for each feature. But the steps I followed were wrong. I thought there was something more complicated. Anyway, if someone gets stuck just like me, here is the solution:

your test inputs are `a1=5` and `a2=7`

For each test input find the euclidean distance **SEPERATELY**

```
d11 = 9    d21 = 9 
d12 = 1    d22 = 1
d13 = 1    d23 = 1
d14 = 9    d24 = 9
```

Now, we need to find the weights, we will do the same thing.(values can be soo close to 0)

```
w11 = 0      w21 = 0
w12 = 0.6    w22 = 0.6
w13 = 0.6    w23 = 0.6
w14 = 0      w24 = 0
```

After finding weights, calculate numerator and dominator for each one.

```
Num1 = w11*3 + w12*5 + w13*7 + w14*9 = 7.2
Num2 = w21*3 + w22*5 + w23*7 + w24*9 = 7.2

Denom1 = w11 + w12 + w13 + w14 = 1.2
Denom2 = w21 + w22 + w23 + w24 = 1.2
```

Output is

```
Num1 + Num2 / Denom1 + Denom2 = 14.4/2.4 = **6**
```